# String doesn't equal string?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, compare

I've been having a glitch in my program for the last couple of hours in development.  After some investigation, shows that one of my string variables apparently not what it says it is.

Lets take a look:

[image]

Now I did edit the photo so you could see the msgbox (which normally wouldn't appear until the next line, I wanted to show it directly next to the tip showing that cT = "dog").

Now, my cT variable is scrapped and read from a stream sent by a junk server I made.  Is there a way to turn cT purely into what it says it is?  It says it's "dog" but something tells me there are some hidden bytes in there or something not showing.  Seeing as "dog" != "dog, does that make any sense?

Thanks for any help you can provide, at this point, I'm baffled.  I'll probably go play some Portal.

**edit**:  Portal just crashed, bad day I guess :/

**edit, here is some code:**

```
Dim cT As String = msg.Split("|")(4).Trim.ToLower
MsgBox(cT.Length)
Dim oct As String = Name.ToLower()
If StrConv(oct, VbStrConv.Lowercase).Contains(StrConv(cT, VbStrConv.Lowercase)) Then
    msend.nMessage(msg.Split("|")(2).Trim & " > All", msg.Split("|")(3))
End If
```

I'm using VB.net so all .net answers are acceptable.

Comment: Have you tried using [`String.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx#Y0) (ie: `cT.Equals("dog")`) instead?

Comment: @NullUserException I'll try that now.  **RESULTS**:  Nope, actually it doesn't work that way either.

Comment: How about `cT.Length = "dog".Length`?

Comment: Did you check the encoding of the string to make sure that it's ASCII or UTF-8 because I've seen issues where reading from a stream that is sending characters in different encodings produces results like this

Comment: @Jesus Ramos, can you provide me with a way to convert it to one or the other so I can test that theory?  Thanks.

Comment: @NullUserException, I'll check that now.

Comment: @NullUserException, I just found out now, cT has a length of 8159...

Comment: 0_0 8159.... are there like 8156 null terminators or whitespace? try ct.Trim() = "dog"

Comment: @Jesus, It actually trims it the line before, you just can't see it :/

Comment: Iterate the string and print out the bytes after dog because it might be that they are not whitespace but terminators if you converted from a byte[] to a string. If they are 0x0 or 0 then you need to truncate the string.

Comment: Would you mind just posting the code snippet than showing us that partial screenshot?

Comment: Can you guys start posting possible answers for this?  I've got to go for the night.  I'll check on this in the morning.

Comment: What's the declaration and source for the `msg` variable?

Comment: You need to post the source that sends the message, as well as the source that receives the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably some invisible characters like 13, 10, or 0 in cT. To see what is really in the string cT, use test code something like this:

```
For i = 0 To cT.Length - 1
  MsgBox(Asc(cT.Chars(i)))
Next i
```

Comment: We've already determined that it does contain characters it shouldn't, how can I remove them?

Comment: They are probably characters < 32. If so, remove everything smaller than a value of 32.

Answer (score 2):

Is there an embedded newline, backspace, or something funky? That can cause WYSI(not)WYG issues...

Comment: We've already determined that it does contain characters it shouldn't, how can I remove them?